# Material ui date picker formatting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want show "Today" text instead of DD/MM/YYYY
Eg: when we use datepicker browser show something like 20/1/2009
But I want "Today" instead of that date

Comment: Pass *Today*(`new Date()`) as an initial value in the state variable and send it to the date picker. I think that'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example where `DatePicker` is initialized with today's date:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField'
import { AdapterDateFns } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns'
import { LocalizationProvider } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider'
import { DatePicker } from '@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker'

export default function BasicDatePicker()
{
  // initialized with today's date, new Date()
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(new Date())

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <DatePicker
        label="Date picker"
        value={value}
        onChange={(newValue) => setValue(newValue)}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  )
}
```

[image]